# Is it possible to reserve memory in icu::UnicodeString?

Tags: c++, internationalization, icu

I am wondering if it is possible to reserve memory in `icu::UnicodeString` (ICU 59.1) similar to how it is done in `std::string` through the `std::string::reserve` method? I have looked through the documentation provided for `icu::UnicodeString`, but have not seen a method that would allow me to do that. Have I missed one, or is it just not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of. Depending on your use case, there is getBuffer(): http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#ae9ea82f86d91d9d978befb155cbec3cf

Comment: @NuSkooler If I am reading this right, `getBuffer()` creates a separate memory allocation from the one containing the original string?

Comment: You can create a UnicodeString, call getBuffer(size) to allocate, then directly do write(s) into the buffer. From there, you releaseBuffer() and the UnicodeString will contain your data.